# PHP array foreach item

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm Having issues grabbing values in a multi level array.

This is my JSON I am grabbing with CURL and putting into a variable.

```
{
  "id": 454626,
  "results": [
    {
      "iso_3166_1": "SK",
      "release_dates": [
        {
          "certification": "U",
          "iso_639_1": "sk",
          "note": "",
          "release_date": "2020-02-20T00:00:00.000Z",
          "type": 3
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "iso_3166_1": "DE",
      "release_dates": [
        {
          "certification": "6",
          "iso_639_1": "",
          "note": "",
          "release_date": "2020-02-13T00:00:00.000Z",
          "type": 3
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "iso_3166_1": "TW",
      "release_dates": [
        {
          "certification": "G",
          "iso_639_1": "",
          "note": "",
          "release_date": "2020-02-21T00:00:00.000Z",
          "type": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my PHP code that I'm having issues with.

```
$id_tmdb = $row[id_tmdb];

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/$id_tmdb/release_dates?api_key=API-KEY",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET"
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

$result = json_decode($response, true);


foreach($result[results][release_dates] as $key=>$val){
    echo "$val[release_date]";
}
```

I'm trying to get the `release_date` but it just shows blank.

I have another page that is formatted the same way so I am unsure why it isn't working.... Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Do you have [error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) turned on? Also, did you copy/paste the code or did you write some of it by hand here?

Comment: copy and pasted it

Comment: Also error reporting is turned on and not reporting anything

Comment: That is weird as you should be seeing at least 4 warnings/notices. So, is your goal just getting all the release dates from all the results?

Comment: Correct need all the release dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$result['results']` value is also an array and you need to iterate over that as well as the `release_dates` array:

```
foreach($result['results'] as $results) {
    foreach ($results['release_dates'] as $val){
        echo "$val[release_date]\n";
    }
}
```

Output (for the sample JSON provided):

```
2020-02-20T00:00:00.000Z
2020-02-13T00:00:00.000Z
2020-02-21T00:00:00.000Z
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/etrR9)

Comment: Ahhhh yes that makes sense. Been hitting my head against the wall for hours. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This should get you there:

```
foreach($result['results'] as $res){
    echo $res['release_dates'][0]['release_date']."\n";
}
```

[3v4l link](https://3v4l.org/n8StF)

On a side-note, I put the array keys in quotes to prevent php warnings.